# Thread.join() replacement in UWP App?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, uwp

I am using some code in a Universal Windows Phone App. .Net for UWP does not have the Thread class. For this purpose we have to use Threadpool class.

For sleep method I used

```
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000).Wait()
```

But I am not able to find what to use for `join()`. Any help?

Comment: In the 'old' ThreadPool there was no facility for Joining either. It would be harmful, and so is `.Wait()`. Redesign your solution to use Tasks and async/await the proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To block the current thread and wait until everything else is completed you can use one of the following:

`Task.WaitAll();` *Waits for all of the provided Task objects to complete execution.*

`Task.WaitAny();` *Waits for any of the provided Task objects to complete execution.*

`Task.Wait();` *Waits for the Task to complete execution within a specified time interval.*